# Content-Disposition empty when using umlauts

Tags: c#, http-headers, content-disposition

I need to double check something. I am using an API to retrieve stored documents from a server. I do it like this

```cs
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var response = await this.Client.SendAsync(message);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    byte[] responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    string filename = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

When I download a document like this, then the `ContentDisposition` is not null and contains the filename in `ContentDisposition.FileName`

Now here's the thing: If the document contained umlauts when they were uploaded and I download the same document via API again, watching at `response.Content.Headers` shows the actual content disposition, but the `ContentDisposition` property itself is null.

[image: ContentDisposition with filename containing umlauts]

Sure, I could probably parse it right from `Headers` with `Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Disposition", out _)` but there has to be a reason for that. I'm not quite sure if that's common practice or an API bug (or even C# bug). Do you have any clues?

Comment: Might it be because non-ASCII characters in the Content-Disposition header value must be escaped? See [rfc2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) section 2.3. Indeed, `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("attachment; filename=Ä.txt");` throws a `FormatException`. It looks like your server is non-compliant, and .NET is being strict. See also [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61197).

Comment: This is interesting and also disappointing. I guess I will just use hex encoding or the method I mentioned above then. Thanks :)